# this.setState React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native

I began learning React native 4 days ago.
I'm trying to pass a property `this` to a different `Scene`, however, I keep **encountering this error** `_this.setState is not a function`.
I believe this isn't a duplicate because I've read through both of these Stack answers and their solutions don't seem to help me. I've got a little bit of a different setup though so thought perhaps that might be the issue.

[React this.setState is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31045716/react-this-setstate-is-not-a-function)

[this.setState is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33381756/this-setstate-is-not-a-function)

I know React has changed a lot in the year since(and does so regularly) these questions were answered so thought perhaps that might be why they didn't work for me.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, Platform, } from 'react-native';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

const Social = () => {
state = {
  name: ''
} 
return (
  <View style={ styles.container }>
    <Text style={ styles.Name } onPress={() => Actions.homepage()}>
      Enter your Name:
    </Text>

    <TextInput style={ styles.TextInput} placeholder='PrimeTimeTran' onChangeText={(text) => {
      this.setState({
         name: text,
      })
    }}
      value={this.state.name}
    />
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => {
        alert(self.state.name)
      }}
    >
      <Text style={ styles.buttonText }>
        Next
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
 );
}

export default Social;
```

I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VTnFDc3IFag) here(22:39) and he seems to get through my problem with no issues. This tutorial was made November 1st, 2016 so I believe there shouldn't be an issue with his syntax.

## One more **possibly important** note,

the only difference I see is that for my constructor, I'm not using a `render()` with `return()` but instead, a `return()` by itself; could this be the issue?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Instead of using functional component change it to `class` component. your `this.state` is `undefined` when you return JSX

Comment: This worked, thanks man. I completely missed this part =). I appreciate your help!

Comment: No one is going to judge you, we all started somewhere. Every programmer was once and probably still is unsure at some level. I have edited your quetstion to remove the heading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your *Social* component is a *stateless functional component* (created here using the () => {} syntax); it's a pure javascript function. Consequently *setState* will not be available. If you need the component to manage its own state you'll need to create it by extending the React.Component:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate

So, you could declare your component as follows:

```
class Social extends React.Component {
  //...implementation here
}
```

You'll then have access to *setState* plus other component lifecycle methods.

(The additional note you added is also because you're using a stateless functional component - these effectively implement the *render* function, so what you can see is just the *return* part of that function.)