# How to bind onclick handlers to `this` properly on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this

Explanation to why this is not a duplicate: My code is already working, I have included as a comment. The question is why the `this` context change when I include it to click handler function.
I'm attempting a calculator project in React. The goal is to attach onclick handlers to number buttons so the numbers are displayed on the calculator display area. If the handler is written directly to render method it is working, however, if I'm trying from the ComponentDidMount I get an error `this.inputDigit is not a function`. How do I bind `this.inputDigit(digit)` properly?

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

export default class Calculator extends React.Component {

// display of calculator initially zero
state = {
  displayValue: '0'
}

//click handler function
inputDigit(digit){
  const { displayValue } = this.state;
  this.setState({
    displayValue: displayValue+String(digit)
  })
}

componentDidMount(){

  //Get all number keys and attach click handler function
  var numberKeys = document.getElementsByClassName("number-keys");
  var myFunction = function() {
    var targetNumber = Number(this.innerHTML);
    return this.inputDigit(targetNumber); // This is not working
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < numberKeys.length; i++) {
    numberKeys[i].onclick = myFunction;
  }

}

render() {
  const { displayValue } = this.state;
  return (
    <div className="calculator">
      <div className="calculator-display">{displayValue}</div>
      <div className="calculator-keypad">
        <div className="input-keys">

          <div className="digit-keys">
            {/*<button className="number-keys" onClick={()=> this.inputDigit(0)}>0</button> This will Work*/}}
            <button className="number-keys">0</button>                
            <button className="number-keys1">1</button>
            <button className="number-keys">2</button>
            <button className="number-keys">3</button>
            <button className="number-keys">4</button>
            <button className="number-keys">5</button>
            <button className="number-keys">6</button>
            <button className="number-keys">7</button>
            <button className="number-keys">8</button>
            <button className="number-keys">9</button>
          </div>
        </div>          
      </div>
    </div>
  )
 }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this.setState is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33381756/this-setstate-is-not-a-function)

Comment: @jmargolisvt Dude I have expained why it is not a duplicate, Also the error message is different. Could you kindly un-downvote the question?

Comment: I didn't downvote you.  Notice that the answers you are getting are the same as I marked in the duplicate. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats because you are writing it inside a function which is not bound,

Use

```
var myFunction = function() {
    var targetNumber = Number(this.innerHTML);
    return this.inputDigit(targetNumber); 
  }.bind(this);
```

or

```
const myFunction = () => {
    var targetNumber = Number(this.innerHTML);
    return this.inputDigit(targetNumber); 
}
```

After this you need to bind the inputDigit function as well since it also uses setState

```
//click handler function
inputDigit = (digit) => {
  const { displayValue } = this.state;
  this.setState({
    displayValue: displayValue+String(digit)
  })
}
```

Since you want to use the button text as well, in that case you should use a separate variable in place of `this` to call the inputDigit function like

```js
class Calculator extends React.Component {

// display of calculator initially zero
state = {
  displayValue: '0'
}

//click handler function
inputDigit(digit){
  const { displayValue } = this.state;
  this.setState({
    displayValue: displayValue+String(digit)
  })
}

componentDidMount(){

  //Get all number keys and attach click handler function
  var numberKeys = document.getElementsByClassName("number-keys");
  var that = this;
  var myFunction = function() {
    var targetNumber = Number(this.innerHTML);
    console.log(targetNumber);
    return that.inputDigit(targetNumber); // This is not working
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < numberKeys.length; i++) {
    numberKeys[i].onclick = myFunction;
  }

}

render() {
  const { displayValue } = this.state;
  return (
    <div className="calculator">
      <div className="calculator-display">{displayValue}</div>
      <div className="calculator-keypad">
        <div className="input-keys">

          <div className="digit-keys">
            {/*<button className="number-keys" onClick={()=> this.inputDigit(0)}>0</button> This will Work*/}
            <button className="number-keys">0</button>                
            <button className="number-keys">1</button>
            <button className="number-keys">2</button>
            <button className="number-keys">3</button>
            <button className="number-keys">4</button>
            <button className="number-keys">5</button>
            <button className="number-keys">6</button>
            <button className="number-keys">7</button>
            <button className="number-keys">8</button>
            <button className="number-keys">9</button>
          </div>
        </div>          
      </div>
    </div>
  )
 }
} 

ReactDOM.render(<Calculator/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I'm getting targetNumber as NaN

Comment: What does `Number(this.innerHTML)` return

Comment: it is returning NaN

Comment: Wait, will create a working snippet and post in a few minutes

Comment: Actually the numbers need to be added to display as string, so i remove `Number`, then I get `undefined`.

Comment: Super! I get it now.

Comment: (y) glad to have helped :). However A more React way would to make use of Refs for DOM handling. I will update the code in the morning, or you can ask a separate question asking the same :)

Answer (score 0):

Bind it in the constructor

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.inputDigit = this.inputDigit.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: OP is using `"plugins": ["transform-class-properties"] ` to not have to do this. Binding every component method can get messy, that's why they're using `state = ` instead of `this.state` inside a constructor.

Comment: `state =` is not in a constructor and you don't need to do that for every single method. Just the one you need to perform callback or any function that subject to context change.