# Cannot call this.setState in addEventListener function

Tags: reactjs

[image]

I am  trying to change the state on the click of a button I created through DOM methods. I tried passing "this" as a variable through the arguments of the function

```
var self="this"
b.addEventListener("click", function(self){
    self.setState({health:100}) })
```

and also tried adding .bind(this) at the end of the function but no luck.

```
b.addEventListener("click", function(){
    this.setState({health:100}) })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this.setState is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33381756/this-setstate-is-not-a-function)

Comment: its lexical scope binding issue.use arrow function in callback or saved `this` in some variable & use inside of callback for setState

Comment: `var self="this"` it should be `var self=this`. remove double quote
 `

Comment: where you deploy this `addEventlistener()` ?

Comment: I deployed it in a function this.restart.bind(this)

Comment: And where you called `this.restart()` ? I just want to know the context of  `this`.

Comment: after the constructor(props) and before the render function

Comment: I mean "call it" not "declare it".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This issue can be handled using right declaration and definition of `self`.
OR with the help of  [`arrow function(implicit Lexical scope)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
componentDidMount(){

  //assuing b defined

  //1.  if you want to use self
  const self = this; //  this should not be double quoted;
  b.addEventListener("click", function () {
    self.setState({ health: 100 });
  }

  // 2. using arrow function ( implicit lexical scope) 
  b.addEventListener("click", ()=> {
    this.setState({ health: 100 });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should do a separate function that manages the event. And then bind the function to the constructor. For example

```
class Toggle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isToggleOn: true};
    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
    }));
  }
render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
        {this.state.isToggleOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
      </button>
    );
  }
```

Also, take in count this :

> When using React you should generally not need to call addEventListener to add listeners to a DOM element after it is created. Instead, just provide a listener when the element is initially rendered.

[Handling Events in react](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
var self=this
```

b.addEventListener("click", function(){
    self.setState({health:100}) })

Remove double quotes from this, it should be working.

Comment: After i removed the double quotes it still says TypeError: self.setState is not a function
HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> i did   var self=this;
   
  b.addEventListener("click", (self)=>{
    self.setState({health:100}) 
    
  })

Comment: I dont get an error message now but when I click the button, the value of this.state.health is still 0

Answer (score 0):

No need const self= this;(optional)
simply use arrow function.this work perfectly

```
b.addEventListener("click", () => {
    this.setState({ health: 100 });
  }
```