# React state don't re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am calling api and getting response then setting response data to state. Problem is state is still undefined after setState and does not update Weather component with api data

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    temperature: undefined,
    icon: undefined,
    time: undefined,
    timezone: undefined,
    description: "123"
  };

  getWeather = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const location = e.target.elements.city.value;
    const api_call = await fetch(`${GEO_API_URL}${location}`);
    const lngLat = await api_call.json();
    console.log(lngLat);

    const api_call2 = await fetch(
      `${API_URL}${lngLat.latitude},${lngLat.longitude}/?lang=sl&units=si`
    );
    const forecast = await api_call2.json();
    console.log(forecast);

    this.setState = {
      temperature: forecast.currently.temperature,
      icon: forecast.currently.icon,
      time: forecast.currently.time,
      timezone: forecast.timezone,
      description: forecast.currently.summary
    };
    console.log(this.state.temperature);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Form getWeather={this.getWeather} />

        <Weather
          temperature={this.state.temperature}
          icon={this.state.icon}
          time={this.state.time}
          timezone={this.state.timezone}
          description={this.state.description}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: from where you call the getWeather method

Comment: Take a look at this answer => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56399937/react-unable-to-setstate-inside-a-promise-then/56403967#56403967

Answer (score 4):

Try using

```
 this.setState({
      temperature: forecast.currently.temperature,
      icon: forecast.currently.icon,
      time: forecast.currently.time,
      timezone: forecast.timezone,
      description: forecast.currently.summary,
});
```

instead of

```
  this.setState = ({
      temperature: forecast.currently.temperature,
      icon: forecast.currently.icon,
      time: forecast.currently.time,
      timezone: forecast.timezone,
      description: forecast.currently.summary,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the right format for the setState method.

```
this.setState({field: 'new value'});
```

Now Change the code setState like.

```
 this.setState({
      temperature: forecast.currently.temperature,
      icon: forecast.currently.icon,
      time: forecast.currently.time,
      timezone: forecast.timezone,
      description: forecast.currently.summary,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

And additionally, to a previous comments I would recommend refreshing the **setState** understanding from official documentation  https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate